# How to select the last cell in a column range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select the final value of a range and put that value into the cell Q4. The range is dynamic and start in the fourth row.

Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim PSpark As Worksheet
    Dim lc As Long

    Set PSpark = Worksheets("ws1")
    lc = PSpark.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With PSpark            
        .Range("Q4") = lc.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, I think you want this:

So we use the column number you found and then pick the value in that last column, for row 4. We copy the value to cell Q4. `Cells(row, column)`

```
Sub test()

Dim PSpark As Worksheet
Dim lc As Long

Set PSpark = Worksheets("ws1")
lc = PSpark.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Gives us the last column number. If the value is in Column C, then we get lc = 3.

    With PSpark

        .Range("Q4") = .Cells(4, lc).Value 'Which row from column lc (which is the last column) we want to copy from

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked Perfectly